# Stripping DataFrame column from text to make integer

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

I couldn't find an easy way to do this and none of the complex ways worked. Can you help?

I have a dataframe resulting from a web-scrape. In there I have a data['Milage'] column that has the following result: '80,000 miles'. Obviously that's a string, so I'm looking for a way to erase all content that isnt numeric and convert that string to straigt numbers
'80,000 miles' -> '80000'

I tried the following:

```
data['Milage'] = data['Milage'].str[1:].astype(int)
```

No idea what the code above does, I took it from another post from here. But I get the following error message:

```
  File "autotrader.py", line 73, in <module>
    data['Milage'] = data['Milage'].str[1:].astype(int)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

The other solution I tried was this:

```
data['Milage'] = str(data['Milage']).extract('(\d+)').astype(int)
```

And the resulting error is as follows:

```
  File "autotrader.py", line 73, in <module>
    data['Milage'] = str(data['Milage']).extract('(\d+)').astype(int)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'extract'
```

I would appreciate any help! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some test problem was `data` is dictionary, you need processing `df` for `DataFrame`.

I think you need remove non numeric values and convert to integers:

```
df['Milage'] = df['Milage'].str.replace('\D','').astype(int)
print(df['Milage'])
0      70000
1      69186
2      46820
3      54000
4      83600
5     139000
6      62000
7      51910
8      86000
9      38000
10     65000
11    119000
12     49500
13     60000
14     35000
15     57187
16     45050
17     80000
18     84330
19     85853
Name: Milage, dtype: int32
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @jezrael, sadly I got the following error message:
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'astype'

Comment: @Csongor - It means `str` is used like variable in your code, can you check?

Comment: Can I drop you a private message somehow? I'd like to share the full code

Comment: @Csongor - check code in my proile, run it for my email

Comment: @Csongor - It looks good, one idea, is possible restart your IDE?

Comment: just did, ran it again in virtualenv and same error :(

Comment: @Csongor - hmmm, is possible upgrade pandas?

Comment: thanks but I'm on 1.1.4, the latest version :(

Comment: Hey, forgot to @jezrael mention you :) let me know if you have any thoughts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225644/discussion-between-csongor-and-jezrael).